# SQL Dynamic Temp Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table  dbo.CTC_GRP...Below is table name and values...

```
**CTC_GRP_DS**
Bank Contact
Dept2
CS
```

I am trying to create a temp table as below..These are column names generated from table column values

```
   Proj_ID   Bank Contact     Dept2     CS
```

My attempts are below...

```
  DECLARE @Dept NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @DeptQry NVARCHAR(MAX)


  SELECT  @Dept = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  QUOTENAME(CTC_GRP_DS) + ' varchar(max)'
                from dbo.CTC_GRP
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @DeptQry = N'Create Table #temptable ( Proj_ID int,' + @Dept + ' '+') '

 print @DeptQry

 EXEC sp_executesql @DeptQry;
```

Till printing @DeptQry i am able to arrive at, how can i excute those dynamic created sql...
can anyone help me on it...

Comment: did you try EXEC sp_executesql (@DeptQry);

Comment: Yes i tried it, but with no luck....

Answer (score 5):

A temp table created within an `EXEC`/`sp_executesql` will be destroyed when that call exits. You need to create the table in the outer scope. You can then modify it with `EXEC` calls. SOmething like:

```
create table #temptable (Proj_ID int)

EXEC sp_executesql N'alter table #temptable add [Bank Contact] nvarchar(max)'
EXEC sp_executesql N'alter table #temptable add [Dept2] nvarchar(max) int'
```

Each new column needs to be added via a separate `alter table` statement, unfortunately.

And obviously, everything that manipulates this table will also have to be dynamic SQL.

Comment: I am in a position to create this table dynamically, by looking itno above suggestion it seems to be we cant not create temptable with dynamic columns...Any other ideas?

Comment: @saravanakumarr - you can create it with dynamic columns, but you need to add each column as a separate statement. And as I tried to emphasise, the key aspect is that you have to have the `create table` in the outer scope